# Why add soda water to beer batter?

Tags: batter

Why "soda water", in the sentence above my red heart?

[image]

[*Seafood Basics: 86 Recipes Illustrated Step by Step* (2012)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/14431129-seafood-basics) by Abi Fawcett,
Deirdre Rooney.

Comment: The common element is carbonation. If you don't have beer (or don't want to use it) you can substitute soda water.

Comment: It actually says "or". Also baking soda can be used if no beer nor soda water are around.

Answer (score 2):

The carbonation in soda water (or beer...or the use of a whipping siphon) is added so that the batter becomes more "airy", leading to a lighter and crispier final result after frying.